# Inability to create VM using virt-manager

Tags: virtual-machine, manjaro, virt-manager

I am trying to create some VM using the `virt-manager` and no matter what I do I am getting this error:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: guest failed to start: Failure in libvirt_lxc startup: Failed to create /var/lib/libvirt/images/vol.qcow2/.oldroot: Not a directory
'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 65, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2001, in _do_async_install
    installer.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 701, in start_install
    domain = self._create_guest(
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 649, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4035, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: guest failed to start: Failure in libvirt_lxc startup: Failed to create /var/lib/libvirt/images/vol.qcow2/.oldroot: Not a directory
```

I have tried to set in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf the user and group to match my user and group, installed libvirt-glusterfs and it doesn’t work. I am using: `libvirtd (libvirt) 7.0.0` and `virt-manager v.3.2.0`.

For the record, I am running Manjaro Linux i3wm and my kernel is 5.11

Comment: There is an error message `Failed to create /var/lib/libvirt/images/vol.qcow2/.oldroot: Not a directory` , have you run `ls -la /var/lib/libvirt/images/vol.qcow2/` ? And verified that the directory, and its parents have the correct permissions? If you have done this, please add that to the question so people can rule that out.

Comment: you are actually right, I have changed the `user` and `group` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` but actually for some reason the `virt-manager` has chosen to use the `LXC` hypervisor instead of `QEMU/KVM`, and I cannot find a way to change that in the preferences or the configuration file.

Comment: How does your connection look like? Do you have a QEMU/KVM connection to "qemu:///system"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Actually, there are two problems, one was that I didn't have `cpio` installed on my machine. This could be easily fixed with `sudo pacman -S cpio`.

The other problem is that by default the `virsh` when run with `sudo` is having different behavior compared to just `virsh` under the current user. This is explained better in this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/803283/how-do-i-list-virsh-networks-without-sudo).

The proposed solutions are either to set the `LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI` or to uncomment `uri_default = "qemu:///system"` in the `/etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf` and eventually also in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/libvirt/libvirt.conf`.

This fixed my problem and now I am able to create VMs with `virt-manager` but I am also recommending checking the [Cockpit Project](https://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/feature-virtualmachines).